# Is there any common lisp docs like linux man?

Tags: emacs, documentation, lisp, common-lisp, manpage

I am a newbie for emacs and common lisp.

I am now using emacs and slime to learn P.Graham “ANSI Common LISP”. However, when I meet something that I don't konw, I can not easily get some useful info like linux man.

Is there any common lisp docs like linux man?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Man or javadoc-style documentation for common lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193313/man-or-javadoc-style-documentation-for-common-lisp)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Front/index.htm) describes the ANSI Common Lisp standard, and, as such, is more similar to [the POSIX Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) than to [Linux man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/).

Since you use Emacs, you can use [`clhs.el`](https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/emacs/clhs.el) to lookup specific symbols there:

```
(autoload 'common-lisp-hyperspec "clhs" "Get doc on ANSI CL" t)
(define-key help-map "\C-s" 'common-lisp-hyperspec)
```

Note: I use <kbd>C-h C-s</kbd> to get the symbol documentation in the browser, you can, obviously, choose your own key binding (use <kbd>C-h C-h</kbd> to see the system bindings).

If you do more than casual Lisp coding, you would probably benefit from using [SLIME: The Superior Lisp Interaction Mode for Emacs](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) instead of the stock facilities.

(If you use [VIM](http://www.vim.org/), [google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=vim%20clhs)).

PS. You should also take a look at the implementation-specific documentation because it documents non-standard features and extensions.

Comment: For Common Lisp HyperSpec and clhs.el, they really works. Thanks.

Comment: CLTL2 is often more helpful than the HyperSpec. It provides guidance and gives the rationale behind each part of the language. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/ai-repository/ai/html/cltl/cltl2.html